# Add html element inside of react component

Tags: html, reactjs

Title is likely wrong to the question. I'm asking, but here is my question. Not sure if this is possible:

I have 2 react components, say

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import Test from './components/Test.js'

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <Test/>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```
import logo from '../logo.svg';


function Test() {

  const savePressed = () => {
    console.log("hello")
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <img onClick={savePressed} src={logo}/>
      <p>
        Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
      </p>
      <a
        className="App-link"
        href="https://reactjs.org"
        target="_blank"
        rel="noopener noreferrer"
      >
        Learn React
      </a>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Test;
```

I know that I can render `Test` inside of `App` as shown, however, I was wondering if I could insert elements directly into `Test` from `App` like such shown below (`<p>` inside of `<Test>`):

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import Test from './components/Test.js'

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <Test>
          <p> hello </p>
        </Test>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

if this is possible, how can it be accomplished? I am aware that this may be against convention (just use props/state to manage stuff like this,) but am curious nonetheless.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can achieve what you described using "Containment" ([see the React documentation on this topic](https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html#containment)).

In other words, whatever you put between `<Test>` and `</Test>` will be passed to the `Test` components in the `children` prop. So in the `Test` component you can do the following:

```
function Test(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <img onClick={savePressed} src={logo}/>
      {props.children}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is [*Containment*](https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html#containment), so your `Test` component would look as follows:

```js
import logo from '../logo.svg';


function Test(props) {          // <-- this changed

  const savePressed = () => {
    console.log("hello")
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <img onClick={savePressed} src={logo}/>
      <p>
        Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
      </p>
      <a
        className="App-link"
        href="https://reactjs.org"
        target="_blank"
        rel="noopener noreferrer"
      >
        Learn React
      </a>
      {props.children}       // <-- this is new
    </div>
  );
}

export default Test;
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do that. But you have to place `<p> hello </p>` inside the `Test` component using props.children. When you place some JSX inside the tags of a component like that, then that JSX element becomes the child of the component. You can access the child from the as `props.children` in your `Test` component and place it where you like.

Example

```
const App = () => {
    return <>
       <h1>Header</h1>
       <Test>
            <p>Lorem ipsome....</p>
       </Test>
       <h1>Footer</h1>
    </>
}

const Test = (props) => {
    return <>
        <h2>Component Start</h2>
             {props.children}
        <h2>Component End</h2>
    </>
}
```